# React function triggered reloading?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

So, I have a parent function `getData()` which will request data from local server. I pass the function to my submit form. I call the function when submitting the form. It get called, but my form state keeps getting reset by itself. Why is this happening?
Also is there a way to refactor my Form useState, I kinda use too many `useState` I guess.
Thanks before.

This is my Form

```
const AddForm = ({ getData, classes }) => {
  console.log("Rendering AddFORM");
  const [checkboxes, setChecked] = React.useState([]);
  const [inputs, setInputs] = React.useState({});
  const [files, setFiles] = React.useState(null);
  const [open, isOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [success, isSuccess] = React.useState(false);
  const history = useHistory();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setInputs({ ...inputs, platform: checkboxes });
  }, [checkboxes]);

  const onChangeForField = React.useCallback(({ target: { name, value } }) =>
    setInputs((state) => ({ ...state, [name]: value }), [])
  );
  const onChangeForFiles = ({ target: { files } }) => setFiles(files);

  const handleCheck = ({ target: { value } }) => {
    checkboxes.includes(value)
      ? setChecked(checkboxes.filter((item) => item !== value))
      : setChecked([...checkboxes, value]);
  };
  const handleClose = () => isSuccess(false);

  async function submitForm() {
    isOpen(true);
    const formdata = new FormData(); // for adding form files i guess
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      formdata.append("files", files[i], files[i].name); // "name", files, filename
    }
    for (let key in inputs) {
      formdata.append(key, inputs[key]);
    }

    const response = await axios.post("/games", formdata);
    const { data } = response;
    isOpen(false);
    isSuccess(true);
    console.log(data.message);
  }

  return (
    <Paper elevation={2} className={classes.Container}>
      <form
        onSubmit={async (e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          await submitForm();
          // getData();
          // history.push("/");
        }}
      >
        <Snackbar open={success} autoHideDuration={6000} onClose={handleClose}>
          <Alert onClose={handleClose} severity="success">
            Game successfully added!
          </Alert>
        </Snackbar>
        <Typography variant="h5" color="initial">
          Add a new game
        </Typography>
        <TextField
          required
          id="standard-required"
          name="title"
          label="Title"
          fullWidth
          placeholder="Game title"
          margin="normal"
          onChange={onChangeForField}
        />
        <TextField
          fullWidth
          multiline
          required
          id="standard-required"
          name="description"
          label="Description"
          placeholder="Description"
          margin="normal"
          onChange={onChangeForField}
        />
        <FormControl margin="normal" fullWidth>
          <FormLabel component="legend">Select Platforms</FormLabel>
          <FormGroup row>
            {platforms.map((p, idx) => (
              <FormControlLabel
                key={idx}
                control={
                  <Checkbox name="platforms" onChange={handleCheck} value={p} />
                }
                label={p}
              />
            ))}
          </FormGroup>
        </FormControl>
        <FormControl>
          <Button variant="contained">
            <label htmlFor="file-upload">Upload Files</label>
          </Button>

          <input
            type="file"
            multiple
            id="file-upload"
            name="images"
            style={{ display: "none" }}
            onChange={onChangeForFiles}
          ></input>
        </FormControl>
        <div className={classes.ButtonsContainer}>
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            type="submit"
            onClick={(e) => {
              e.stopPropagation();
            }}
          >
            Submit
          </Button>
          <Button variant="contained" color="secondary">
            <Link to="/">Go Back</Link>
          </Button>
        </div>
      </form>
      <Backdrop className={classes.backdrop} open={open}>
        <Paper elevation={3} className={classes.Loading}>
          <Typography variant="body1" align="center">
            Submitting your form
          </Typography>
          <CircularProgress color="primary" className={classes.Circular} />
        </Paper>
      </Backdrop>

      <Button onClick={() => isSuccess(true)}>Text</Button>
    </Paper>
  );
};
```

This is the parent which hold the `getData()`

```
function App() {
  const [games, setGames] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  async function getData() {
    const response = await axios.get("/games");
    const { data } = response;
    setGames(data);
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
      <Container maxWidth="lg" style={{ margin: "1.5rem auto" }}>
        <Switch>
          <Route
            path="/"
            exact
            component={() => <GameList games={games} getData={getData} />}
          />
          <Route
            path="/add"
            exact
            component={() => <AddForm getData={getData} />}
          />
          <Route path="/addimg" exact component={() => <ImageForm />} />
          <Route
            path="/games/:id"
            exact
            component={() => <GameDetails getData={getData} />}
          />
          <Route
            path="/games/:id/edit"
            exact
            component={() => <EditForm getData={getData} />}
          />
          <Route
            path="/games/:id/reviews/:rid/edit"
            exact
            component={() => <EditReviewForm getData={getData} />}
          />
        </Switch>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

You are rendering all your components on routes with anonymous components via the `component` prop, this cause new components to be created and mounted.

[component](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/component)

> When you use `component` (instead of `render` or `children`, below) the
> router uses `React.createElement` to create a new React element from the
> given component. That means if you provide an inline function to the
> component prop, you would create a new component every render. This
> results in the existing component unmounting and the new component
> mounting instead of just updating the existing component. When using
> an inline function for inline rendering, use the `render` or the
> `children` prop (below).

## Solution

Use the `render` prop to pass additional props to your route components.

Since `ImageForm` component isn't being passed any additional props it can be passed directly to the `component` prop of a `Route`.

Additionally, you should reorder your routes so you specify more specific paths prior to less specific paths, so they can be attempted to be matched first. This removes the need to append the `exact` prop to every route for matching.

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/add" render={() => <AddForm getData={getData} />} />
  <Route path="/addimg" component={ImageForm} />
  <Route
    path="/games/:id/edit"
    render={() => <EditForm getData={getData} />}
  />
  <Route
    path="/games/:id/reviews/:rid/edit"
    render={() => <EditReviewForm getData={getData} />}
  />
  <Route
    path="/games/:id"
    render={() => <GameDetails getData={getData} />}
  />
  <Route
    path="/"
    render={() => <GameList games={games} getData={getData} />}
  />
</Switch>
```

> Also is there a way to refactor my Form useState, I kinda use too many
> `useState` I guess.

IMO you don't have "too may" state hooks. You can either keep all your state values simple and separate, or you can combine them into a more complex state object. Selecting one over the other is a subjective issue. In *my opinion*, each "chunk" of state should be capable of standing on its own, as a single atomic entity. As such it seems you've separated the state concerns sufficiently (checkboxes, inputs, toggles, etc...). I think trying to merge your state would only make your state updates needlessly more complex.